# Following documentation to "Create a custom functions project", getting "Error installing add-ins"

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I have followed the guide for creating a custom functions project:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-custom-functions-quickstart?tabs=excel-windows

When I run `npm run start:desktop` Excel opens. The Excel instance can show a taskpane from the addin. When Excel opens the status bar says "Add-ins loaded successfully" but after a while it changes to "Error installing add-ins". And when I enter `=CONTOSO.ADD(10,200)` into a cell no formula with that name exists.

Do you have any idea what might be the problem or what would be good next steps for troubleshooting? I have already tried clearing Office cache.

EDIT 1: To clarify in response to a comment, I believe that the web server is started when I execute `npm run start:desktop`. The foreground process starts Excel and then exits soon after with the output in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Make sure that a web server has been started.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev: I added edit1 to address your question. I think that the web server has been started.

Answer (score 0):

I did follow the same article, just to check this out. I noticed that your screenshot doesn't have the line `Enabled debugging for add-in a6778cd6-b54f-4602-8dd2-919218581f2c.`

```
App type: desktop
Enabled debugging for add-in a6778cd6-b54f-4602-8dd2-919218581f2c.
Starting the dev server... (webpack serve --mode development)
Sideloading the Office Add-in...
Debugging started.
```

which may be because something missing in the source, that has setup by `yo office` or some issue/incompatibility of node-modules like `office-addin-debugging`, `webpack`.

So I would suggest to run `npm run stop` and make sure no *developer add-ins* are listed under *My Add-ins* and clear that cache [manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache).

Then try to create the same sample in another folder by running the `yo office` and follow the steps from there onwards.

Before you run `npm run build`, delete the *package-lock.json* file. There should be another window (webpack) open once you run the `npm run start:desktop` and should remain till you run `npm run stop`

Here is the screenshot of webpack window. I used `Node v14.19.3` and `npm 6.14.17` to test this.
[image]

Hope this has give some next steps to troubleshoot.

Comment: With that version of node/npm I get "Error: Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/core'"

Comment: Here are the dependencies I used. Make sure that you delete the package-lock.json before run `npm i`



      ```"dependencies": {"ajv": "^8.11.0", "ajv-dist": "^8.11.0", "core-js": "^3.9.1", "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7"}```